# Passing data from view to controller with ajax/jquery, codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

i just want to pass data to controller with ajax, which is selected by dropdown menu in view. Here is my try http://pastebin.com/KnLqW8Pc.

```
    //// controller ///////    
<?php         
    class Ilce extends CI_Controller{         
            public  $ilceid;         
            public function __construct()
            {
                    parent::__construct();
                    $this->load->model('ilce_model');
            }

            public function index()
            {      
                    $this->load->helper(array('form'));
                    $data['ilce'] = $this->ilce_model->ilce_getir();

                    $this->load->view('ilce', $data);
                    /*
    hello, i want to print here to data which will select in view and passed by jsfunc file ( ajax ) to here again...
    */       

            }               
    }


/////////////////////////////////view/////////////////////////////////
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/reset.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/page.css"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/3burcak.ico"  />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jfunc.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>3Burçak Ltd.Şti.</title>

    </head>
    <?php echo  form_open('ilce/index')?>






    <select id="ilce" name="ilce">
    <option value="">Select Town</option>
    <?php foreach ($ilce as $x):?>
    <option value="<?php echo $x['id']?>"><?php echo $x['ad']?></option>
    <?php endforeach?>
    </select>
    <select id="semt">
    <option value="">Please select Town first.</option>
    </select>






////////////////////////////////////////////////////////jsfunc
```

$(document).ready(
    function(){

```
    /* il ilce arama*/
    $("#ilce").change(
        function(){
           if($("#ilce").val()!="-1"){
              var ilceid=$("#ilce").val();
               $.post('ilce/index',{"ilceid":ilceid},function(output){
                    $('#semt').remove();
                    $('#semt').append(output);

               });

           }
        });

        /* il ilce arama bitti*/





    });
```

Comment: you didn't tell us your problem.

Comment: i comment my problem  in controller class.. i can't pass selected item to controller with ajax. i think there is a problem in js file.

Comment: Please post your code in the question as well so if the link is not active any more, people will still have reference to the code in question.

Answer (score 0):

My friend, the code that you have posted is too un formatted to understand, but from what I understand you want to pass view info to ajax request. If that is the case, then the way to do it call a page as your ajax request which is inside your controller in this case "Ilce". Here say you are requesting the index page, so load a view for example $this->load->view('xyz', $data); and this will pass you the desired result.

You can also check this tutorial which in detail shows how to get ajax data using Code Igniter and jQuery Ajax: http://amitavroy.com/justread/content/articles/getting-ajax-data-using-views-codeigniter

Hope this help

Comment: thanks for answer, i'm also reading your page already:) by the way, sorry i can't use here effectively yet im noob. i mean, i select data from db and pass it to view with form_dropdown. after this, if someone select something from selectbox, it will pass to controller again with ajax and i want to do this. for example; $this->var = $passed_data_from_view_with_ajax;

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to load a view like that from an AJAX call. Make a separate function to return the data to the view then your append will work.

jQuery

```
$("#ilce").change(
     function(){
        if($("#ilce").val()!="-1"){
            var ilceid=$("#ilce").val();
            $.post('ilce/ajax_return_data',{"ilceid":ilceid},function(output){
                    $('#semt').remove();
                    $('#semt').append(output);

               });

       }
    });
```

Controller

```
function ajax_return_data()
{
    $this->load->helper(array('form'));
    $data['ilce'] = $this->ilce_model->ilce_getir();
    print json_encode(array('output'=>$data['ilce']));
}
```

Comment: Rick, still doesnt work, actually i want to this, if someone select item from selectbox, it's id will pass to controller back and i will use it there something like this: $this->var = $var_came_from_ajax;